# How to import stencils and source into android eclipse?

Tags: android

I just download the stencils and source from ANDROID DEVELOPERS http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html
but I don't know how to import the stencils into the eclipse and so I can use them? any idea?? thanks a lot for any help ^^